# How to Capture the Authorization Bearer Token from DOM structure in Network tab using selenium with Java

Tags: java, api, selenium, oauth-2.0, rest-assured

Looking for Capturing the Authorization code from DOM structure in Network tab using Selenium with Java an pass that token to rest Assured header as "Authorization", "Bearer"

Please suggest/help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this AuthorizationCode element in the DOM have a specific html id that you can search by?, or its parent has an id?

Using the driver, you can get an element by its ID:

```
// by id
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("XXElementId"));
// by name
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("XXElementName"));
// by class name
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("XXClassName"));
// by tag name
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.tagName("XXTagName"));
// by class selector
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea#elementId"));
// by xpath
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='elementId']"));
```

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1053815/Grab-and-Parse-Data-using-Selenium-WebDriver-Part

https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/locating_elements/

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot do that because DOM presents the UI, cannot manipulate the Network tab. You may check the `cookie` to find the `access_token` I'm not quite sure.